# [ionic]How to get wifi signal strength value

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

How to get wifi signal strength in an ionic app.

I found this
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-signal-strength
but I still don't understand how to use 
can some one please give me an example app?

by clicking button, I need the value of signal strength.

Sorry if it's a dumb question but I'm really beginer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have made a working demo app for this plugin. But as mentioned in https://github.com/petervojtek/cordova-plugin-signal-strength  " when you call  for the first time the device may respond with -1. Try calling the function again after some delay"

I am sharing my repository.

https://github.com/kushcrimson/wifi-strength.git

Good Luck.

Comment: Hello,Thank you very much for demo app.
first button click it return -1 and I wait for a while and click button again it return value equal 85
images
http://imgur.com/a/zBxTl

Comment: Glad to hear ,I was helpful. Please upvote this answer :) thanks

Comment: Hello again,I want to use this plugin 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-wifiinfo-plugin 
can you make a demo app for me  please T.T(i'm sorry)

Comment: I have update the code in git ,press twice for result :)

Comment: Thank you for your kindness.

Comment: How to do if I want to show only BSSID,Rssi,SSID. I try {{info.BSSID}} 
{{info.Rssi}} 
{{info.SSID}} but didn't work

Comment: that's because $scope.info is not object it's string . So i updated the code over git for changes (y)

Comment: wow you are very intelligent,finally i can continue my project.thank you very much. >.<

Comment: Glad I was of any help :) not sure about intelligent though :D

Comment: Hello  Ujjwal kaushik Could you please help me solve this problem

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40739259/ionichow-does-interval-work-in-background